# How to update a particular list of array of lists in state in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using an array in state like this -

```
this.state = {
     shapes : []
}
```

and shapes array contains data in lists like this-

```
[
   {x: 0, y: 0, height: 10, width: 10},
   {x: 10, y: 10, height: 11, width: 11},
   ...and many more
]
```

I have taken the x and y coordinates and changed their values.
For ex - for item 1 new values =>
 x = 15 and y = 15

How can I update these values in the state?
Sorry about my improper question. I can't think of another way of asking this question.

Comment: Wait shapes is array and you then you said shapes contains data like this `{ ... }` (an object). means each index have object like this?

Comment: shapes is an array and Yes, each index of array contains these types of objects. Sorry if it was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give while array value as new in set state

```js
this.setState((state) => ({...state, shapes:[{x:15:y:15}, ...state.shapes.slice(1)]}))
```

Comment: what if I don't know the index? How can I update when I don't know the index

Comment: Do you know the previous data? If so you can find index from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
   const newItems = [...prevState.shapes];
   newItems[1].x = 15;
   newItems[1].y = 15;
   return {shapes: newItems};
});
```